# Limit number of files in folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a folder name /clientupload/ in my host. I want to limit the number of files in clientupload folder and its sub-folder to total 200.

I dont have any idea how to do that!

Comment: Why do you want to limit the number of files in a folder to 200?

Comment: I am allowing client to upload their document, so i want to limit number of files they can upload. Also main reason is Inode limit

Comment: Unless you're building something on the scale of Facebook you shouldn't worry about inode limits.

Comment: Just create a directory for each hour? That might work.

Comment: @michaelb958 I am having multiple website hosted under single shared hosting account! I always need to look out for inodes limit!
Also I can take more money from client for more file limit! :-)

Comment: I've rollbacked your edit. It's very confusing for everyone to find an answer posted as question. And next time you have a question about your PHP code please post the PHP code you want to fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check (via php) amount of files in folder before letting the user upload the file

ive changes this to work with sub-folder.

for example (you might need to change a bit didnt run this....) :

```
<?php

  define("MAX_UPLOAD_AMOUNT", 200);
  //switch to your dir name
  $dirName = "/Temp/";
  //will count number of files
  $totalFileAmount = countFiles($dirName);

function countFiles($dirName){


    $fileAmount = 0;
  //open dir
  $dir = dir($dirName);

  //go over the dir
  while ($file = $dir->Read()){
    //check there are no .. and . in the list
    if (!(($file == "..") || ($file == "."))){
        //check if this is a dir
        if (Is_Dir($dirName . '/' . $file)){
            //yes its a dir, check for amount of files in it 
            $fileAmount += countFiles($dirName . '/' . $file);
        }
        else{
        //its not a dir, not a .. and not a . so it must be a file, update counter
        $fileAmount++;
        }
    }
  }

  return $fileAmount;
}

    //check if user can upload more files
    if ($totalFileAmount >= MAX_UPLOAD_AMOUNT)
        echo "You have reached the upload amount limit, no more uploaded";
    else
        echo "let the user upload the files, total number of files is $totalFileAmount"; 

  ?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't that last `if` be `if ($size >= MAX_UPLOAD_AMOUNT) { echo "You can't upload more files" }`?

Comment: @user1809599 Take note of the `>=` - if you use `>` instead, the user will be limited to 201 files instead of 200.

Comment: It does not count the files in sub-folder! not good as expected!

Comment: @user1809599 Is there any reason you want the user to be able to create subfolders? Preventing that may be easier.

Comment: It includes whole folder as 1 file only! check with   print_r($fileArr);

Comment: @michaelb958
I have a cms where there is option to create folder and add and edit new files. The root folder where the files are stored is /admin/file/
Each file is made without extension to avoid search engine index or malware e.g. /admin/file/testingfile
so if anyone want to download file then i use php header to download as testingfile.html or testingfile.txt. The file downloadhtml.php and downloadtxt.php make this download with renamed extension possible and it is saved in /admin/file/ folder which a user can save or edit. so i decided to write notice in website that make sub-folder...

Comment: ...make and save the file or folder user like! So i need to count sub folder. also user can create many subfolder and I need to accumulate the number of files of all folder and do -4 for two download php files and two useless file (.) (..)

It is like ftp editor. I also want to hide these two download php files from hiding from user so that they cannot edit the code of that with web editor, or download feature would stop working!

Comment: @user1809599 whats why they invented debug mode :)

Comment: to check why it isnt printing anything ... probably a small thing causing this not to work

Comment: I have mark your answer as Accepted answer please say me what is problem in your code, i cannot debug it

Comment: @N.L.telaviv I also made my code, it is also working!Anyways thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Have found a working solution on my own! You can try the below code. 200 is the file limit which you can change!

```
<?php

define("MAX_UPLOAD_AMOUNT", 200);

function scan_dir($path){
    $ite=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);

    $bytestotal=0;
    $nbfiles=0;
    foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename=>$cur) {

        $nbfiles++;
        $files[] = $filename;
    }

    $bytestotal=number_format($bytestotal);

    return array('total_files'=>$nbfiles,'files'=>$files);
}

$files = scan_dir('folderlinkhere');

if ($files['total_files'] >= MAX_UPLOAD_AMOUNT)
        echo "Files are more than 200.  ";
    else
             echo "Carry out the function when less than 200";
?>
```